# Trying to replace a char by another into a map

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace W by OU only if the char before him is at position 0 of the string and if it's a consonnant and only the first W in the String, ie TWITWIC --> TOUITWIC.

Here is my code (tampon is the input i give to the code into my test):

```
public class Phonkw {
    static Map<String, String> consonnantReplace = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static {
         consonnantReplace.put("BW", "BOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("CW", "COU");
         consonnantReplace.put("DW", "DOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("FW", "FOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("GW","GOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("HW","HOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("JW", "JOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("KW", "KOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("LW", "LOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("MW", "MOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("NW", "NOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("PW", "POU");
         consonnantReplace.put("QW", "QOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("RW", "ROU");
         consonnantReplace.put("SW", "SOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("TW", "TOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("VW","VOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("WW", "WOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("XW","XOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("ZW", "ZOU");            
    }

    public static String phonkw1(final String tampon){
        if (tampon==null){
            return "";
        }
        if(consonnantReplace.containsKey(tampon)){
            return consonnantReplace.get(tampon);
        }
        return tampon;
    }

}
```

I think i need to substring tampon at (0,1) but i cant get the value in map byt the substring.

EDIT : RESOLVE.

Comment: Is this code not working? It just returns the text which should replace the original text but it does no replacing.

Comment: Why not use a regex? `s/^([BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ])w/$1ou/` would be the regex. `tampon = tampon.replace("^([BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ])w", "$1oiu");` in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to stick to your `Map` solution, you will indeed need to use `substring()`. For the lookup, you want to go for `substring(0, 2)` because that will be the first two characters of the `String tampon`. However, be aware that this will `throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in case of single-letter-words, so a guard checking the length would be required.

This is your code modified accordingly:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Phonkw {
    static Map<String, String> consonnantReplace = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static {
         consonnantReplace.put("BW", "BOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("CW", "COU");
         consonnantReplace.put("DW", "DOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("FW", "FOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("GW","GOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("HW","HOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("JW", "JOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("KW", "KOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("LW", "LOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("MW", "MOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("NW", "NOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("PW", "POU");
         consonnantReplace.put("QW", "QOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("RW", "ROU");
         consonnantReplace.put("SW", "SOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("TW", "TOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("VW","VOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("WW", "WOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("XW","XOU");
         consonnantReplace.put("ZW", "ZOU");            
    }

    public static String phonkw1(final String tampon){
        if (tampon == null){
            return "";
        }
        if (tampon.length() >= 2) {
            final String key = tampon.substring(0, 2);
            if (consonnantReplace.containsKey(key)) {
                return consonnantReplace.get(key) + tampon.substring(2);
            }
        }
        return tampon;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        for (final String arg : args)
            System.out.println(phonkw1(arg));
    }
}
```

You could actually create your `Map<String, String>` with a loop. If you do not intend to modify the `Map` during runtime, you can also wrap it with `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` to prevent it from accidental modification.

And you might fix the spelling mistake, it's `consonant`, not `consonnant`.

The code would then look like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Phonkw {
    private static final Map<String, String> consonantReplace = createConsonantReplaceMap();

    private static Map<String, String> createConsonantReplaceMap() {
        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        final String consonants = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ";
        for (final char consonant : consonants.toCharArray())
            map.put(consonant + "W", consonant + "OU");
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    public static String phonkw1(final String tampon) {
        if (tampon == null) return "";
        if (tampon.length() < 2) return tampon;
        final String key = tampon.substring(0, 2);
        if (consonantReplace.containsKey(key))
            return consonantReplace.get(key) + tampon.substring(2);
        return tampon;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        for (final String arg : args)
            System.out.println(phonkw1(arg));
    }
}
```

You don't really need a `Map` if all the entries are uniform replacements. In that case you could directly check, like this:

```
public class Phonkw {
    private static final String CONSONANTS = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ";
    public static boolean isConsonant(final char c) {
        return CONSONANTS.indexOf(c) != -1;
    }
    public static String phonkw1(final String tampon) {
        if (tampon == null) return "";
        if (tampon.length() < 2) return tampon;
        if (tampon.charAt(1) == 'W' && isConsonant(tampon.charAt(0)))
            return tampon.charAt(0) + "OU" + tampon.substring(2);
        return tampon;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        for (final String arg : args)
            System.out.println(phonkw1(arg));
    }
}
```

With a regular expression, the code could be even simpler:

```
public class Phonkw {
    public static String phonkw1(final String tampon) {
        return tampon == null ? "" : tampon.replaceAll("^([BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ])W", "$1OU");
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        for (final String arg : args)
            System.out.println(phonkw1(arg));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to solve this issue, check in the comments for a good regex to use

If you want to use a non-regex solution you could consider the following code. You can indeed use a [`String.substring`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm), or use [`String.charAt`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm) for a single character

```
public class Phonkw {
    public static String phonkw1(final String tampon){
        if (tampon==null){
            return "";
        }
        if (tampon.length() > 1 && isConsonant(tampon.charAt(0)) {//the first character is a consonant
            if (tampon.charAt(1) == 'W') {//the 2nd character is a W
                return tampon.charAt(0) + "OU" + tampon.substring(2); // not an optimal solution..
            }
        }
        return tampon;
    }

    public static boolean isConsonant(char c) {
        return "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ".indexOf(c) != -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong because it does not check whether the character before the "W" is a consonant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited my post with a workaround

Comment: But that's still not what the OP was asking about. The first character needs to be a consonant. Your code would also convert "AW" to "AOU", which is not intended.

Comment: Oh I see, my english failed on me there. I will remove this answer shortly. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Why not simply add a check `isConsonant()` to your answer? That would actually be nice code then.

Comment: Figured that was the way to go ;-) This update to my post should suffice. Thanks again

Comment: That's already better. Just, you're checking for vowels, not consonants ;) How about `public static boolean isConsonant(final char s) { return "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ".indexOf(s) != -1; }`?

Comment: Ah, I see. Had a quick lookup on what a consonant is. You learn something everyday. I used your suggestion in my answer. It should be fine now! Appreciate the constructive feedback

Comment: Now you might want to fix the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` which are thrown when you use `charAt` and `tampon.length() < 2`. :)

Comment: Heh, you are right. You are not one easy fellow to please ;) Edited once again.

Comment: Don't rely on me spotting *every* bug. But still, I hope to catch most of them just by reading code. Those which I don't spot, I hope to find in my unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should replace anything before 'W' that is a consonant but only if that consonant is at position 0 in the string.

```
public class Phonkw {
    static Map<String, String> consonnantReplace = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static {
        consonnantReplace.put("BW", "BOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("CW", "COU");
        consonnantReplace.put("DW", "DOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("FW", "FOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("GW", "GOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("HW", "HOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("JW", "JOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("KW", "KOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("LW", "LOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("MW", "MOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("NW", "NOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("PW", "POU");
        consonnantReplace.put("QW", "QOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("RW", "ROU");
        consonnantReplace.put("SW", "SOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("TW", "TOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("VW", "VOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("WW", "WOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("XW", "XOU");
        consonnantReplace.put("ZW", "ZOU");
    }

public static String phonkw1(String tampon) {
    if (tampon == null) {
        return "";
    }

    Iterator<String> it = consonnantReplace.keySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String s = it.next();
        if (tampon.indexOf(s) == 0) {
            tampon = tampon.replace(s, consonnantReplace.get(s));
        }

    }

    return tampon;
}

}
```

A regex might be another solution?